# Javascript function not being called at all

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mobile

I made the following small Javascript script to enable some form elements on my page:

```
function unHide()
{
    if($('#UserName').val() == "")
    {
        alert('Please Enter a User Name first');
    }
    else
    {
        $('#radio-choice-1').checkboxradio('enable');
        $('#radio-choice-2').checkboxradio('enable');
        $('#radio-choice-1-board').checkboxradio('enable');
        $('#radio-choice-2-board').checkboxradio('enable');
        $('#TransNum').textinput('enable'); 
        $('#UserContinue').remove();
        $('#nextButton').show();
    }
}
```

The problem is, this isn't being called when the correct button is clicked. Even the alert doesn't show up. Here is the HTML:

```
<label for="UserName" style="vertical-align: top;">User Name:</label>
<input type="text" name="UserName" id="UserName" placeholder="Ex: LesniakBjEVS101" />

...

<a data-role="button" data-icon="check" data-mini="true" id="UserContinue"
    style="float:right;" onclick="javascript:unHide(); return false;">Continue...</a>

...

<section id="nextButton" hidden>
    <a href="salamanderSelect.html" data-role="button" data-icon="forward" 
             data-mini="true" style="float:right;">Next</a>
</section>
```

The problem I am encountering is when I click on the submit button, absolutely nothing happens. I am not getting any feeback from the Javascript, nor anything.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks!

Edit:

After trying out suggestions, I still am unable to get the javascript to do anything. I have tried multiple browsers, but still nothing.

And I just had this working yesterday too...without any changes to the code too

Edit 2:

Apparently it works if my script is the last thing in the HTML file, even outside of the  tags.

Comment: Is anything showing up in your console?

Comment: Just a suggestion to put the click handler in code NOT in markup. Easy with jQuery `$('#UserContinue').click(function(){unHide();});`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While onclick doesn't need `javascript:`, it should still work in many browsers.  Here is a jsfiddle of your example: http://jsfiddle.net/ukWcp/2/

Only use `javascript:` in an `href`.

While i suggest debugging using the javascript console and debugger in firebug or chrome, others have mentioned using an all javascript solution for your bindings.  That is preferrable.

Answer (score 4):

As you're using jQuery already, why not use it to attach your events, rather than using the clunky `onclick` attribute.

```
<a data-role="button" data-icon="check" data-mini="true" id="UserContinue"
style="float:right;">Continue...</a>
```

```javascript
$("#UserContinue").click(function(e) {
    if($('#UserName').val() == "") {
        alert('Please Enter a User Name first');
    }
    else {
        $('#radio-choice-1').checkboxradio('enable');
        $('#radio-choice-2').checkboxradio('enable');
        $('#radio-choice-1-board').checkboxradio('enable');
        $('#radio-choice-2-board').checkboxradio('enable');
        $('#TransNum').textinput('enable'); 
        $('#UserContinue').remove();
        $('#nextButton').show();
    }
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: I never knew you could do it like that...is this the preferred way to do it? Thanks!

Comment: This is definitely best practice for adding events via jQuery.

Comment: @Brendan Even if you're not using jQuery, adding events using regular Javascript is also preferred since it gives you greater separation between the Javascript and HTML.

Comment: I just tried this solution in both Firefox and Chrome, and it still did not work. I'm not getting anything in the console nor any feedback of any kind.

Comment: Where are the `checkboxradio` and `textinput` methods coming from? Are you using a plugin?

Comment: OR `$('#UserContinue').click(function(){unHide();});`

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss Better yet: `$('#UserContinue').click(unHide);`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Yep, another way to do it since not passing any parameters.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#UserContinue").click(function() {
        if($('#UserName').val() == "")
        {
            alert('Please Enter a User Name first');
        }
        else
        {
            $('#radio-choice-1').checkboxradio('enable');
            $('#radio-choice-2').checkboxradio('enable');
            $('#radio-choice-1-board').checkboxradio('enable');
            $('#radio-choice-2-board').checkboxradio('enable');
            $('#TransNum').textinput('enable'); 
            $('#UserContinue').remove();
            $('#nextButton').show();
        }

        return false;
    ); 
});
```

If you're using jQuery, why not fully use it?  The return false at the end stops the click event from continuing if that was what you desired.

Edit:

You say in your original post "The problem I am encountering is when I click on the submit button, absolutely nothing happens. I am not getting any feeback from the Javascript, nor anything."

Yet you have attached a click event to your incomplete anchor tag (it's missing the href).  So are you expecting the behavior to trigger on clicking the submit button or clicking the anchor tag?  If you are expecting the trigger to fire on clicking the submit button, then you need to change $("#UserContinue") to reference the submit button and not the anchor tag.  Or use the .submit() event handler instead of .click(), http://api.jquery.com/submit/.

If this is not the issue, then I suggest editing your post to include all of your code and saying what behavior you expect after clicking which elements.

Edit 2:

I believe you are not wrapping your jQuery around the .ready() function, please see the revised code snippet that now includes .ready().  .ready() ensures the DOM is fully loaded before working with your jQuery.

Comment: I just tried this solution in both Firefox and Chrome, and it still did not work. I'm not getting anything in the console nor any feedback of any kind.

Answer (score 1):

Keep your function and add the event handler to your javacript and NOT in markup:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('#UserContinue').click(function() { 
       unHide();
    });
});
```

short version:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('#UserContinue').click(unHide);
});
```